# Assign a user group to a structure entry. Restrict permission front end page to that same group

Tags: users, permissions

I'm working on a website for a school. Each group has a specific page that has video's for that group only. Members of that group do not need access to the CP. First I noticed that I can only assign specific members to an entry, using the Users field. I'm not able to assign a group at once.

How can I make it possible for the teacher to assign a group to a video through the CP (not the code), and that only that group can view the page after login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to try a different approach.

I made two dropdown fields "studentlevel", one for the user where the admin can set the level from 1 to 12 and one in a matrix block with the video's, also from 1 to 12.

I've set a conditional:

```
{% for block in entry.videos %}
   {% if currentUser.studentlevel <= block.studentlevel %} 
      video here
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since the studentgroup has no access to the CP, they can't change it and they'll only see the video up to their skill level.

Comment: That's a great solution. Much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no way to assign a 'group' using an entries `fieldType`. What I would likely do is create a category group called 'User Groups' (userGroups) that mirror my groups, with fields for 'title' and 'groupId'.

- Group Title 1 -> 1,
- Group Title 2 -> 2,
- Group Title 3 -> 3,
- etc.

(Unfortunately, I think the only way to get the groupId is to look in the database `craft_usergroups` table. Although the code below could probably be adapted to use the group handle if needed.)

Then create a categories fieldType called 'authorizedGroups', and add it to the video channel's `fieldLayout` (or wherever else you need it). The client would then be able to select groups via the `authorizedUserGroups` field that have authorization to the video.

In your template(s) you can then check for videos related to the `authorizedGroups` that match the `currentUser.group` and display content accordingly.

First, on your videos index page you would only want to only show links to the videos that the user has authorization to view.

```
{% if currentUser %}
    {# create an array of the currentUser.groups Ids #}
    {% set currentUserGroupIds = [] %}
    {% for group in currentUser.groups %}
        {% set currentUserGroupIds = currentUserGroupIds|merge([group.id]) %}
    {% endfor %}

    {# find all userGroupCategories that match currentUserGroupIds #}
    {% set userGroupCategories = craft.categories.group('userGroups').find({
        groupId: currentUserGroupIds
    }) %}

    {# find all the videos related to userGroupCategories #}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('videos').relatedTo(userGroupCategories) %}
    <ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href={{ entry.url }}>{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Then on the video detail page you would use a conditional that redirects any unauthorized users to a 401 page (or to any other page that you choose).

```
{% set userIsAuthorized = false %}
{% for group in entry.authorizedUserGroups %}
    {% if currentUser.isInGroup( group.groupId ) %}
        {% set userIsAuthorized == true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if not userIsAuthorized %}
    {% redirect 401 %}
{% endif %}

{# display video #}
...
```

**Update**: There was a significant code error that did not account for the fact that user.groups returns an array of groups rather than a single group. I rewrote the code to handle this. Untested, and probably still contains errors, but should be closer at least.

Comment: There was a major code error. `curentUser.groups` returns an array of groups, rather than a single group. I have updated the code to (hopefully) deal with multiple groups. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Found another error. 'currentUserGroupIds|merge(group.id)' should be an array 'currentUserGroupIds|merge([group.id])'.

Comment: You're a machine, Douglas.